# r last observation carried forward unless no further observations

Tags: r, statistics, zoo

I have a data set that takes serial temperature measurements for several patients. The dataset is patchy and contains many NA values. However, patients may have died before the end of the experiment and therefore had NAs recorded from the time of death until the end of the measurement period. What I want to do is go through my dataframe by rows (individual patients) carrying the last observation forward UNLESS there are no further observations recorded. A small example dataframe would be:

```
df<-data.frame(H0=c(35.4, 36.0, 36.0, 36.4), H1=c(NA, 34.0, 33.4, NA), 
           H2=c(NA, 33.5, NA, 34.2), H3=c(32.9, NA, 34.0, NA),
           H4=c(NA, 33.1, NA, NA), H5=c(33.2, NA, NA, 32.8))
```

I have kind of got it working with zoo and apply with:

```
df2<-apply(df, 1, na.locf)
```

Although that creates a matrix and not a dataframe, and carries the temperature forward for a dead patient until the end of the experiment, which is not what I want to do. Patients 2 & 3 should both still end in H5 with an NA.

Answer (score 2):

Transpose, use `na.fill` to fill in the trailinig NAs with 0 and use `na.locf` to fill in the remaining NAs and transpose back.  Finally replace the zeros with NAs:

```
library(zoo)

df0 <- t(na.locf(na.fill(t(df), c(NA, NA, 0))))
ifelse(df0 == 0, NA, df0)
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] 35.4 35.4 35.4 32.9 32.9 33.2
[2,] 36.0 34.0 33.5 33.5 33.1   NA
[3,] 36.0 33.4 33.4 34.0   NA   NA
[4,] 36.4 36.4 34.2 34.2 34.2 32.8
```

It could alternatively be written like this:

```
zero2NA <- function(x) ifelse(x == 0, NA, x)  
t(apply(df, 1, function(x) zero2NA( na.locf( na.fill(x, c(NA, NA, 0))))))
```

Comment: +1 nice workaround.. I guess no patient will have temperature 0 so there shouldn't be and 0s in the data to start with :)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `?na.locf` you will see there is an option na.rm to retain *leading* NAs. So by reversing twice you can make it preseve trailing NAs. The problem is that in this case it uses the endpoint rather than the first point of the interval it is replacing and using fromLast together with na.rm doesn't fix this (the NAs are not preserved). So an ugly but working solution is to first preserve the NAs (but replace with the wrong values), then replace with the right values (without preseving NAs) and finally correct by re-inserting the NAs where they should be... It's not pretty but it works

```
res1 <- t(apply(df, 1, function(y) rev(na.locf(rev(y), na.rm = F))))
res2 <- t(apply(df, 1, na.locf))
res2[is.na(res1)] <- NA
res2
#       H0   H1   H2   H3   H4   H5
#[1,] 35.4 35.4 35.4 32.9 32.9 33.2
#[2,] 36.0 34.0 33.5 33.5 33.1   NA
#[3,] 36.0 33.4 33.4 34.0   NA   NA
#[4,] 36.4 36.4 34.2 34.2 34.2 32.8
```

*Edit* A more compact and elegant approach suggested by @G.Grothendieck

```
tdf.na <- na.locf(t(df), fromLast = TRUE)
t(ifelse(is.na(tdf.na), NA, na.locf(t(df))))
#       H0   H1   H2   H3   H4   H5
#[1,] 35.4 35.4 35.4 32.9 32.9 33.2
#[2,] 36.0 34.0 33.5 33.5 33.1   NA
#[3,] 36.0 33.4 33.4 34.0   NA   NA
#[4,] 36.4 36.4 34.2 34.2 34.2 32.8
```

Comment: Good idea. Suggest this slightly shorter variation: `tdf.na <- na.locf(t(df), fromLast = TRUE); t(ifelse(is.na(tdf.na), NA, na.locf(t(df))))`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thanks, that seems much better actually. I didn't realise it was possible to pass the whole data frame in `na.locf` directly...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base solution:

```
t(apply(df, 1, function(a) {
    i <- is.na(a)
    ifelse(rev(cummin(rev(i)) != 1), a[which(!i)[cumsum(!i)]], NA)
}))

##       H0   H1   H2   H3   H4   H5
## [1,] 35.4 35.4 35.4 32.9 32.9 33.2
## [2,] 36.0 34.0 33.5 33.5 33.1   NA
## [3,] 36.0 33.4 33.4 34.0   NA   NA
## [4,] 36.4 36.4 34.2 34.2 34.2 32.8
```